# Cannot update MikTex or install packages

Tags: miktex, update

I am running MikTex2.9.6888, on a Win 7 64 machine and on a Win 10 Home laptop, and MikTex console in admin mode. I cannot update MikTex nor install packages. I keep getting "internal MikTex error." On the MikTex.org prerequisite page it says you need either Win 10 64 or Win 11 64. So even if I reinstall MikTex to the latest build it will not run on either of my machines. Do I really have to buy Win 10 64 to update this program?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The prerequisites are quite clear and if they say you need win 10 + 11 64bit I would believe it.  (You can update some packages manually, but not the binaries).  For texlive 2023 you will need a 64bit system too. The alternative is to use an online system like overleaf.

Comment: For Win Xp/Vista/7 machines MikTex will not update. If the owner of the machines makes no changes to MikTex then the system is still usable. The packages used for the documents needs the latest version then the owner of the machine can find, or obtain from CTan or other source, the current version which can be placed in the same folder as the document being worked on. Otherwise proceed onward as before with trust that LaTeX will continue to produce great documents.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to update MikTex from my Win 10 laptop even though it isn't 64-bit (Win 10 Home). Just a case of bad info on the MikTex site, but I'm not complaining. all is well.